# Verify that $A \oplus B$, where $A$ and $B$ are cyclic groups of orders 2 and 3, is the cyclic group of order 6

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let's define $A$ and $B$ as follows:

$A$ = {e,a}
$B$ = {e,b,2b}

Then
$A\oplus B= \{\{e+e\},\{e+b\},\{e+2b\},\{a+e\},\{a+b\},\{a+2b\}\}$
which is equal to $\{\{e\},\{b\},\{2b\},\{a\},\{a+b\},\{a+2b\}\}$

This has 6 elements including the identity, but how do I know it's cyclic? I can see that if we have $a=3b$, then we get $\{\{e\},\{b\},\{2b\},\{3b\},\{4b\},\{5b\}\}$. Is that enough for the problem to be verified?

Comment: Elements of the direct sum are ordered pairs. Find a generator to show it's cyclic.

Comment: Aren't {e+e},{e+b},{e+2b},{a+e},{a+b},{a+2b} the sums of ordered pairs?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt He's just working in additive notation. In multiplicative, calling $A=\langle a|a^2=1\rangle$ and $B=\langle b|b^3=1\rangle$, it looks like $A\times B=\{1,a,ab,ab^2,b,b^2\}$

Comment: Ah, so 'direct sum' doesn't necessarily have to be a sum? It can be whatever operation the group is defined as having?

Comment: $A\oplus B=\{ (e,e),(e,b),...\}$. Sums of ordered pairs would be like $(a,b)+(e,2b)=(a,e)$.

Comment: So $A \oplus B= \{(e,e),(e,b),(e,2b),(a,b),(a,2b),(a,e)\}$?

Comment: As $(a,b)$ can be summed to itself to generate all the other elements, it's a generator and hence the group is cyclic and (as can easily be checked) of order 6?

Comment: That is indeed the case.

Comment: Note: it only makes sense to write $a+b$ if $A,B$ are assumed to be subgroups of some larger abelian group. Without knowing this, it's preferable to write $a\oplus b$, with the caveat that we only add "$a$'s to $a$'s" and "$b$'s to $b$'s".  The symbol "$\oplus$" is just a SEPARATOR here, we could write $\langle a|b\rangle$, or $(a,b)$, or $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}$ or a number of other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Taylor said, just find a generator (and it's the obvious one. If still confused, I can give a hint).

In general, you can show that $\mathbb{Z}_m\times\mathbb{Z}_n\cong\mathbb{Z}_{mn}\iff \gcd(m,n)=1 $

Comment: Ok, so is it just $b$?

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to write $a$ in terms of $b$. You should be keeping $a$ and $b$ separate as they're elements from different groups (like you had before you made the substitution $a=3b$).

Comment: Finding a generator is pretty easy by trial and error. There are only 6 elements to check, and 2 of them work.  (And $b$ does not work.)

Comment: Right. So I guess the generator must be the identity element?

Comment: In fact, once you realize that an element of $A$ can't work, because the subgroup it generate would be included in $A$, and an element of $B$ can't work for an analogous reason, then the only elements left to check are the two that work --- so you'd have "trial without error."

Comment: Try all six elements, as @AndreasBlass said, and see which one, adding to itself 6 times, will generate each element of the group.

Comment: Ah ok, got it, sorry for being so slow :) It must be $a+b$, because it generates $a+b,2b,a,b,a+2b,e$. Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: Actually, $a+2b$ also works